# how to remove everything inside directory except a list of files and directories?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, posix

I need to delete everything inside `dist/` folder except `manifest.json` and `index.html` and `assets/`. It will run as script inside `package.json`.

I tried solving it with find

`"clean": "find dist ! -name manifest.json -type f -delete | find . -type d -empty -delete"`

But I couldn't get it to work with multiple arguments.

edit:

So I want to keep:

`dist/assets/*` everything inside assets. Including subdirectories like `dist/assets/map/dog.ts`
`dist/manifest.json`
`dist/index.html`

and delete the rest, for example:

`dist/pages/` delete directory, subdirectories and files
`dist/examples/` delete directory, subdirectories and files
`dist/randomfile.txt` delete file
`dist/hello.js` delete file
`dist/*` etc. etc.

Comment: Your requirements are not fully clear. Please [edit] your question and add more details. Do you want to keep the named files and directory in `dist/` only or in any subdirectory of it? Based on your `find` commands I assume you want to delete directories that are empty after removing files and subdirectories, right?

Comment: @Bodo I'm sorry. I updated the question. Let me know if it needs more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [current version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70427113/3) of the question you want to keep

- `dist/assets/` (and everything inside)
- `dist/manifest.json`
- `dist/index.html`

and remove everything else inside `dist`.

For testing I used this `find` command.

```
find dist -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
  -type f \( -name manifest.json -o -name index.html -o -print \) -o \
  -type d \( -name assets -o -print \)
```

If the output lists everything that should get removed in `dist` you can run the version that actually deletes the data.

```
find dist -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
  -type f \( -name manifest.json -o -name index.html -o -print -delete \) -o \
  -type d \( -name assets -o -print -exec rm -rf "{}" \; \)
```

Explanation:

- global options `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` to limit the search to all files and directories directly below `dist`.
- `-type f \( actions1 \) -o -type d \( actions2 \)` use AND (`-a` or nothing) and OR (`-o`) operations to execute `actions1` for files and `actions2` for directories, use escaped parentheses because AND operation has higher precedence than OR. (If there are any other objects in `dist` (e.g. symbolic link, named pipe, ...) you might have to add conditions and some action to catch the other cases.
- `-name manifest.json -o -name index.html -o -print -delete` OR operation: if one of the first expressions (matching name) is true, the last one (`-print -delete`) is not executed
- `-name assets -o -print -exec rm -rf "{}" \;` similar to above, use `rm -rf` for recursive removal because `-delete` will not remove non-empty directories.

---

Alternative solution:

- rename `dist`
- create a new `dist`
- move the files and directory you want to keep to the new `dist`
- recursively remove the old renamed directory.

```
mv dist dist.tmp && mkdir dist &&
  mv dist.tmp/assets dist.tmp/manifest.json dist.tmp/index.html dist && 
  rm -rf dist.tmp
```